# Update node revision programmatly

Tags: 8

If i try to update node revision like this:

```
$node = node_revision_load(59);
$node->set('publish_on', null);
$node->save();
```

or simple save:

```
$node = node_revision_load(59);
$node->save();
```

I have a PHP memory error, (i have 1gb allocated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a node, you should always check if it exists (is not null) before calling a method:

```
$node = node_revision_load(59);
if ($node) {
  $node->set('publish_on', null);
  $node->save();
}
```

But this is not the cause for the memory error. This is more likely a recursive thing. For example you are saving again and again until the memory is filled up.

Comment: ! It is correct, my problem was in incorrect logic that created a loop